# affirm vs confirm

Tags: difference, legalese

> According to the Confederation Congress's Northwest Ordinance of 1787, slavery would be banned from the vast federal territory north and west of the Ohio River and east of the Mississippi, but slave-state masters would have the right to recapture any bondsmen who might escape onto this newly free soil.
>   Yet this ordinance, adopted in New York City in July, gave fugitives less procedural protection than did Article IV, drafted in Philadelphia a month later.[Footnote omitted] The ordinance **affirmed** the common-law right of masters to recapture fugitives on their own, without coming before a magistrate..

Source: P 260, *America's Constitution: A Biography*, Akhil Reed Amar

I recognise [Definition 1.2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/affirm), but why or why not write  **confirm**? What are the similarities and differences? For instance, [Definition 1a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affirm) for **affirm** contains **confirm**.  I already tried https://english.stackexchange.com/a/27874, [this forum thread](http://wordcraft.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/932607094/m/8616019153?r=8606002253#8606002253).  *I ask not only its use in legalese, but in English generally.*

Comment: Why are you getting definitions from forum threads instead of a dictionary? [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/affirm) affirms the connection between "affirm" and "confirm", as well as its usage in legal terms.

Answer (score 5):

Particularly in legal contexts, ***affirm*** can be exactly synonymous with ***confirm***, but the more general principle distinguishing these two words is as indicated by OP's cited forum thread. Essentially,...

> 1: ***affirm*** - *to [strongly] assert something*
>    2: ***confirm*** - *to endorse something*

...where the "something" in #1 might in principle never have been conceived of or articulated by anyone prior to being *affirmed* for the first time. That's as opposed to the context in #2, where "something" must previously have been stated (or at least, *recognised as a possibility*) before being *confirmed*.

---

It's unduly anthropomorphic to quibble with constructions using something "non-sentient" (such as an [*ordinance*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordinance)) as the subject of the verb. It's true people wouldn't normally use *"This document **thinks** the world is flat"*, but it's perfectly normal for documents to ***say, assert, claim, affirm, confirm, postulate*** something in such contexts.